# Retrieve Image from NextJS API route

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am using Next.js with Typescript. I have a situation where the Next.JS client is on a different host than the Next.JS server.

The client would like to display an image from `localhost:3001/....` (a different service), but that service only exists on the Next.JS server machine, *not* where the browser is. Therefore, I have to proxy my URLs through the Next.JS server. I did this by wrapping all of my `src`s in the image tags with a function that rewrites the URL to something like `/api/image-rewrite?orig=<base 64 of original URL>`. This part works fine.

I then end up in the Next.JS API route `image-rewrite`, where I parse out the original URL from the `orig` search parameter and then call `fetch` on it from there. The `fetch` returns the image. I can verify this by checking the content-type and content-length.

I then want to forward this image back to the Next.JS client; however, I'm running into issues where this is just not occurring. Here is the relevant code (please note I have left out obvious error checking - assume everything is valid and exists and content type is correct (image/jpeg) and content length has a size):

```
// Parse out the original URL and fetch it
const parsedURL = Buffer.from(originalURL as string, 'base64').toString('ascii');
const orig_url = new URL(parsedURL);
const full_url = new URL(`${BASE_URL}/render${orig_url.search}`);
const imgResp = await fetch(full_url);

// Grab the necessary information (body, content type, content length)
const body: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null = imgResp.body;
const contentType: string | null = imgResp.headers.get('Content-Type');
let contentLength: string | number | null = imgResp.headers.get('Content-Length');
contentLength = Number(contentLength);

// Send response to client
res.writeHead(
    200,
    {
        'Content-Type': contentType,
        'Content-Length': contentLength as number
    }
);
```

At this point, I have tried several different methods:

Just trying to write out the `imgResp` body:

```
return res.write(body);
```

Using `stream` to stream the body into `res` ("no overloads match this call"):

```
stream.pipeline(body, res);
```

Using the body to pipe ("Argument of type 'NextApiResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'."):

```
body.pipeTo(res);
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this works, but here is the answer I found that works:

```
const resp = await axios({ url, method: 'GET', responseType: 'stream' });

// Various errors checks...

await new Promise<void>(
    (resolve) => {
        resp.data.pipe(res);
        resp.data.on("end", () => { resolve(); });
    }
);
```